# Can we execute a java program without any arguments in main()?

Tags: java

Why does main() should be called only with String type parameters? can't call main() without any arguments?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.
for example, suppose you have 2 possible overwrite for main , one with string parameters and one with none , so you can use 2 main in your program!
and how it understand which one is your real main?